# Nodejs email send error

Tags: node.js, outlook, nodemailer

I'm trying to send an outlook email with nodemailer package.

my code:

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
    secureConnection: false,
    port: 587,
    tls: {
        chipers: 'SSLv3'
    },
    auth: {
        user: 'user@domain.com'
        pass: '123456'
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'user@domain.com',
    to: 'user@domain.com',    //Same user (send to myself)
    subject: 'Nodejs Mail',
    text: 'this is the email\'s body text...'
}


transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error) console.log(error);
    else console.log('Message sent successfully: ' + info)'
});
```

When I run my node app I get the following error:

> Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN smtp-mail.outlook.com:587...

The user is exist (I can send manual email to this user using outlook).

Why I get this error and how can I solve it? thanks a lot.

Comment: That error means the DNS resolution failed. Something actually went wrong - can you dig/nslookup `smtp-mail.outlook.com` from wherever this is running?

Comment: Youre righ, I can't. How can I figure out what the smtp address is? @Catalyst

Comment: I just checked and I can `nslookup` that domain, returning a bunch of addresses. The problem is that you aren't able to do DNS lookups. If you can't use nslookup on windows to resolve `smtp-mail.outlook.com` then there's some network configuration you'll have to fix. Maybe re-ask this question related to the platform you're running on, asking about dig/nslookup failure